# Bootstrap 4 issue when displaying in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having issue with my bootstrap page. I am trying to create a login form with header logo but when I am viewing it in my mobile it is not correctly displayed.

I am using bootstrap 4.5.2

Here's my HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <img src="Images/logo-lg.png" alt="logo" class="img-fluid"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <center>
                                    <img width="150px" src="Images/profile.svg"/>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <center>
                                    <h3>Member Login</h3>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label>Username</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtUsername" runat="server" placeholder="Username" required></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtPassword" runat="server" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password" required></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" ID="btnLogin" OnClick="ValidateUser" runat="server" Text="Login" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="Registration.aspx">
                                        <input class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg" id="btnRegistration" type="button" value="Sign Up" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div id="dvMessage" runat="server" visible="false" class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <strong>Error!</strong>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's what it looks like when I am viewing it on my mobile.

[image: Sample Image]

I want it to be the logo at the top of the login details when it is resize to mobile.

Comment: This is how it looks: https://nimb.ws/Abg5jy Your expected behavior. Moreover `<center>` tags are deprecated. Demo: https://llz5m.csb.app/ If your code is not working like that, update it.

Comment: Yes but in my mobile phone it is not working. It seems that it's looking for a certain size of the screen

Comment: It will only work in the browser but not in your mobile phone..

Comment: Tested on mobile phone: https://nimb.ws/4OxMiR

Comment: @StackOverflow what is the width of your phone's display?

Comment: @StackOverflow you can use the media queries for specified widths. what is the width of your mobile phone. or what is your phone model.

Comment: It didn't work on my mobile phone. My phone is Samsung S21 Ultra

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
```

Instead of

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

For both the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Grid System here is the link:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/